# Ignite with backup count zero

Tags: ignite

I have set backup count of ignite cache to zero. I have created two server node(say s1 and s2) and one client node(c1). I have set cache mode as Partitioned.  I have inserted data in ignite cache. Stopped server 2 and tried access data it is not getting data. If backup count is 0 then how to copy data from one server node other server node. Does ignite does automatically when we stop node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Ignite manages this is with backups. If you set it to zero, you have no resilience and removing a node will result in data loss (unless you enable persistence). You can configure how Ignite responds to this situation with the Partition Loss Policy.

Comment: Unfortunately, Apache Ignite does not have safe shutdown with partition disowning. It is expected to be supported some point in the future.

Comment: do you mean I  cannot use backup count zero?

Comment: @DipakJadhav Correct. If you want to scale down like this, set backups=1.